# Awk to get file1 column and check column1 of file2,if matches then print the corresponding value

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to compare the first column of file1, with the first column of file2. if there is match-> print the corresponding value that is in column2 of file2

Checked some suggestion around but didnt find the right code.

```
file1 (single column)
987
675
21
23
21
2645

file2 (two columns)
234 def
987 one
22  abc
21  two
675 three
24  rty
25  qwe
```

Expected output:

```
one
three
two
two
```

Im using:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { r[$1] = $0; next; } r[$1] { print r[$1]; next }' file2 file1
```

and i get this:

```
987 one
675 three
21  two
21  two
```

Any suggestion?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work...

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{r[$1]=$2; next} $1 in r{print r[$1]}' file2 file1
```

essentially, if you don't want to print first field, just store the second field in your `r` array.

The second `next` is redundant; also check the existence of the field in array with `in`, since the value might be zero (or null string) in which case `r[$1]` will be false.